# inequality proof consisting of complex number modulus and intergers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> Let $m,n$ be integers greater than $1$.  Let $\zeta$ be a complex number. Suppose $0<|\zeta|<\frac12$. Then
> $$
> \frac{1-|\zeta|-|\zeta|^m}{1-|\zeta|}<|(1+\zeta^m)(1+\zeta^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1+\zeta^{m+n})|<\frac{1-|\zeta|}{1-|\zeta|-|\zeta|^m}.
> $$

I tried to use induction to prove.

$P(n)$:

$\dfrac{1-|\zeta|-|\zeta|^m}{1-|\zeta|}<|(1+\zeta^m)(1+\zeta^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1+\zeta^{m+n})|$

$P(2)$: (I tried to “simplify” the inequality)

$\dfrac{1-|\zeta|-|\zeta|^m}{1-|\zeta|}<|(1+\zeta^m)(1+\zeta^{m+1})(1+\zeta^{m+2})|$

$1-\dfrac{|\zeta|^m}{1-|\zeta|}<|(1+\zeta^m)(1+\zeta^{m+1})(1+\zeta^{m+2})|$

$1-|\zeta|^m(\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}|\zeta|^x)<|(1+\zeta^m)(1+\zeta^{m+1})(1+\zeta^{m+2})|$

Then I stuck here, can anyone give me some hints?

Edit:

I have another thought just now.

$\frac{1-|\zeta|-|\zeta|^m}{1-|\zeta|}<|(1+\zeta^m)(1+\zeta^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1+\zeta^{m+n})|$

$1-\frac{|\zeta|^m}{1-|\zeta|}<|(1+\zeta^m)(1+\zeta^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1+\zeta^{m+n})|$

$1<|(1+\zeta^m)(1+\zeta^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1+\zeta^{m+n})|+ \frac{|\zeta|^m}{1-|\zeta|}$

Now, let $P(n)$ be $1<|(1+\zeta^m)(1+\zeta^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1+\zeta^{m+n})|+ \frac{|\zeta|^m}{1-|\zeta|}$

This time, I start at $P(0)$:

$|1+\zeta^m|+\frac{|\zeta|^m}{1-|\zeta|}>|1+\zeta^m|+|\zeta|^m= |1+\zeta^m|+|\zeta^m|\ge |1+2\zeta^m|$

Then I stuck here.

Second Edit:

I have proved that:

(A):

$\frac{1}{1-|\zeta|}\ge 1+|\zeta|\ge |1+\zeta|\ge 1-|\zeta|$

(B):

$|(1+\zeta^m)\cdot (1+\zeta^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1+\zeta^{m+n})$

$=|1+\zeta^m|\cdot |1+\zeta^{m+1}|\cdot …\cdot |1+\zeta^{m+n}|$

$\ge (1-|\zeta|^m)\cdot (1-|\zeta|^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1-|\zeta|^{m+n})$

(C):

$1-|\zeta|^m-|\zeta|^{m+1}-…-|\zeta|^{m+n}$

$\le (1-|\zeta|^m)\cdot (1-|\zeta|^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1-|\zeta|^{m+n})$

$\le \frac{1}{1+|\zeta|^m+|\zeta|^{m+1}+…+|\zeta|^{m+n}}$

Then I stuck here.

Third edit:

(C) (rectified):

$1-|z|^m-\frac{|z|^{m+1}(1-|z|^n)}{1-|z|}$

$1-|z|^m-|z|^{m+1}-…-|z|^{m+n}$

$\le (1-|z|^m)\cdot (1-|z|^{m+1})\cdot …\cdot (1-|z|^{m+n})$

$\le \frac{1}{1+|z|^m+|z|^{m+1}+…+|z|^{m+n}}=\frac{1}{1+|z|^m+ \frac{|z|^{m+1}(1-|z|^n)}{1-|z|}}$

I am not sure whether this is useful so I don’t combine this into the second edit.

Comment: Do you want other proofs?

Comment: Sure. But I guess my second edit is very close to an end. But I just stuck there lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the right inequality:

Let $x = |\zeta |$. We have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1 - x}{1 - x - x^m} &= \frac{1}{1 - x^m/(1 - x)} \\[5pt]
 &> \mathrm{exp}\left({x^m/(1 - x)}\right)\tag{1}\\
 &= \mathrm{exp}\left({\sum_{k=m}^\infty x^k}\right) \\
 &\ge \mathrm{exp}\left({\sum_{k=m}^\infty \ln(1 + x^k)}\right)\tag{2}\\
 &= \prod_{k=m}^\infty (1 + x^k)\\
 &\ge \prod_{k=m}^{m+n} (1 + x^k)
\end{align*}
where we have used $\mathrm{e}^{-v} > 1 - v$ for all $0 < v < 1$ in (1), and $\ln(1 + u) \le u$ for all $u \ge 0$ in (2).

Using $|1 + \zeta^k| \le 1 + |\zeta|^k$, the right inequality is true.

---

For the left inequality:

**Fact 1**: Let $y_k \in [0, 1), \, \forall k$. Then $(1 - y_1)(1 - y_2)\cdots (1-y_N)
\ge 1 - (y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_N)$.
(*Note*: Use Mathematical Induction and $(1 - a)(1 - b) \ge 1 - (a + b)$ for all $a, b \ge 0$.)

Using Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1 - x - x^m}{1 - x} &= 1 - x^m/(1 - x)\\
 &= 1 - \sum_{k=m}^\infty x^k\\ 
 &< 1 - \sum_{k=m}^{m+n} x^k\\
 &\le \prod_{k=m}^{m+n} (1 - x^k).
\end{align*}

Using $|1 + \zeta^k| \ge 1 - |\zeta|^k$, the left inequality is true.

Comment: Thank you. That’s cool.

Comment: @鈴木悠真 You are welcome.